# Flex 4 Advanced datagrid column summation based on another column value

Tags: flex4, advanceddatagrid

In my advanceddatagrid there are two columns A and B. The records are such as 
{column A: id1, columnB:50},{column A: id1, columnB:20},{column A: id2, columnB:80},{column A: id21, columnB:20}

ie, for a single column A values there might be many column B values(one to many relationship).
I need to do a summation of column B values for every column A values.I need to check for a particular column A what is the sum of column B.

Kindly let me know as how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Each object(i.e., item) in column A has an array of values in column B.
So sum up the array in column B

check summation of array elements.

Comment: the datagrid data is a flattened view.